# How can I edit my conversion tag setup?

Tags: google-analytics, google-adsense

My end goal is just to be able to edit my conversion tracking setup in google ads. Also note i'm using "smart mode" not expert mode so there's some things I might not be able to see.

In simply mode I went to:

1. My example campaign
2. "Conversions"
3. Then "View your tracking ID and instructions"

It asks me to insert the same tracking snippet (that I put into my website already when i was previously instructed by google analytics). Now this snippet is inserted but when I click "test connection" it says "No Google Analytics was found on your website. Please follow the snippet installation instructions and try again."

That snippet is definitely functioning though, as I'm getting live analytics from the site.
It wont let me continue with setting up tracking instructions until this test is passed but i have no clue what I'm doing wrong.

here is the first 23 lines of my home page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>
    Briland  </title>
  

      
                <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-207891956-1">
</script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-207891956-1');
</script>
```

Comment: I think that tag is firing btw...I see multiple analytics.js requests in network tab

Comment: what site are you referring to? i never gave url

Comment: Your GA tracking code is in the code block

Answer (score 3):

Ok so I switched to expert mode and then i could click "settings"> "conversion" i could then edit my conversion triggers there.

Comment: I am wondering if this was just a caching issue. It might have taken Google several minutes to recognize that your tracking script was installed, then you would have been able to configure that from either interface. I know that sometimes it takes a few minutes when I install analytics, myself.